# avoiding stack overflow in binary tree construction

Tags: haskell, optimization, lazy-evaluation, strict

as a part of learning haskell i decided to write a binary tree.

as far as i understand, if i sequence a large set of insertions and deletions i can easily reach a stack overflow when i finally start evaluating even if the resulting tree is relatively small.

here are my questions then:

1. can i avoid this by introducing some strictness to my function? (something with seq / deepseq?).
2. in which situations would i want to keep insetion/deletion in its current state?

feel free to correct or improve my code if you feel it is designed badly or incorrect.

the relevant code:

```
import Data.List

data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
              deriving (Eq)

leaf x = Branch x Empty Empty

-- insert ------------------------------------
treeInsert :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
treeInsert Empty x  = leaf x
treeInsert (Branch y l r) x | x<y = Branch y (treeInsert l x) r
                            | x>y = Branch y l (treeInsert r x)
                            | otherwise = Branch x l r  --edit


-- delete ------------------------------------
treeDelete :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
treeDelete Empty _ = Empty
treeDelete (Branch y l r ) x    | y<x   = Branch y l (treeDelete r x)
                                | y>x   = Branch y (treeDelete l x) r
                                | y==x  = del' $ Branch y l r
    where
    -- if this Branch is a leaf dispose of it.
    -- if branch has only one child return the child (skip over).
    -- otherwise, replace this branch with its successor (the leftmost child of the right tree)
    --      successor will be extracted from its original location.
    del' ( Branch y Empty Empty )   = Empty
    del' ( Branch y Empty r )       = r
    del' ( Branch y l Empty )       = l
    del' ( Branch y l r )           = Branch ySucc l rWithout_ySucc

        where
        ( rWithout_ySucc, ySucc ) = leftmost r

            where
            leftmost ( Branch y Empty Empty )   = ( Empty, y )
            leftmost ( Branch y Empty r )       = ( r, y )
            leftmost ( Branch y l r )           = ( Branch y ll r, z ) where ( ll, z ) = leftmost l
```

Comment: I don't think `treeInsert` does what you intended.

Comment: @augustss please elaborate

Comment: What does it do when thing inserted item is already there?

Comment: replaces it, its a tree with no duplicates.

Comment: It looks to me like it throws away the left and right branches.

Comment: ... your eyes deceive you!! (corrected in an edit, thank you for noticing)

Comment: @jajdoo: you can use profiling (heap profiling in particular) to experiment with different variants and check memory consumption; there is also Vacuum (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum) which helps visualise evaluation degree of expressions

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to make a structure stricter is not to make the functions on it stricter, but to alter the type itself.

In this case we can change

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

to

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a !(Tree a) !(Tree a)
```

And this will mean that any time you have a `Branch`, the two `Tree`s contained, will also be forced to their head. Since the `a`s inside the tree are not strict, but just the structure itself, this is called `spine-strict` and is a very typical pattern.

The reason you may not want to do this at times is that now you pay the "full cost" for all operations at once -- deleting an element from say five levels down in the tree will force all five levels of reconstructing a new tree to be performed at once, whereas if you never needed to actually look down those paths, they would otherwise never have been forced.

So there are certain structures ([Okasaki](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) described them very well) where in order to get the correct *amortized* asymptotic performance, you *don't* want to add additional strictness.

In fact, you can typically avoid stack overflows simply by enforcing strictness *at the use site*. So, imagine you had a `fold` over an empty tree that successively inserted a zillion elements. If you use a *strict* `foldl'` (even with a lazy tree) then you will end up consuming much less stack than if you used a lazy fold.